# Struggling to install scvi-tools on Mac M1

Tags: software-installation

I was wondering if somebody here has experience with installing scvi-tools on a Mac with M1 chip. I tried the following command:

```
conda install scvi-tools -c conda-forge
```

But got the following error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to
download and install packages.
Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /conda-forge/osx-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

Then I tried to install OpenSSL with following command:

```
conda install -c anaconda openssl
```

and I got the exact same error as the conda install scvi-tools -c conda-forge command.

I do not understand why collection of metadata is failing for openssl. Any inputs would be highly helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: There might be system incompatibilities, thats what my error log suggests. Thus I was unable to easily install as well. However this might be a Python version  issue (could be Python 3.6, I used 3.11 [not the best idea]). However the error log should have flagged that. `scvi-tools` is a bioinformatics tool, but please try and edit the question with the biological problem. I'd guess this is RNA-seq PCA type analysis

Comment: Wait, how did you end up with a non-working conda install on that M1 mac in the first place?  Looks like it's not complaining about a missing package dependency; it's complaining about not having openssl to do HTTPS downloads within conda.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
pip install scvi-tools
```

?

Comment: Would need venv (virtual env) with pip, but I agree I think this is the best approach in this particular scenario

Comment: https://scvi-tools.org/